# Etale fundamental groups of algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Is the étale fundamental group of an algebraic group always abelian? Is a complete calculation of them available somewhere, at least for reductive groups over fields of char. 0?

Comment: In the trivial case that $G = Spec(F)$, where $F$ is our base field, then the etale fundamental group of $G$ is the absolute Galois group of $F$, which is often nonabelian (e.g., if $F = \mathbb{Q}$). But maybe you wanted a less trivial example, in which case, the following blog post by Akhil Mathew might interest you: https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/the-etale-fundamental-group-of-an-algebraic-group-is-not-necessarily-abelian/

Comment: "Is the étale fundamental group of an algebraic group always abelian?" - since $\pi_1^{et}(G)$ is defined as a limit of galois groups $G(K'/K)$ of galois extensions $K \subseteq K'$ where $G(K'/K)$ is non-abelian in general, you should not expect $\pi_1^{et}(G)$ to be abelian in general.  Over the complex number field an affine algebraic group $G$ has abelian topological fundamental group. Hence if $\pi_1^{et}(G)$ is the profinite completion of $\pi_1(G)$, this proves $\pi_1^{et}(G)$ is abelian. Maybe you find this proved in SGA.

Comment: @AlexWertheim, The moral of Akhil's blog post and of de Jong's comments below it seems to be: it should be true in char 0, but false in char p.

Comment: @AlexWertheim, But Spec(F) is not an algebraic group, is it?

Comment: @Simplicius I mean, over algebraically closed fields, at lesat in char 0 this is true--although I'm not sure why you'd really need it a priori. For connected groups $G$ use the fact that $R_u(G)$, being a unipotent group in char 0, is isomorphic as a scheme to some affine space. By the existence of a Levi decomposition we know that, as schemes, $G\cong R_u(G)\times (G/R_u(G))$ and so since we're in characteristic $0$ the etale fundamental group

Comment: splits and so $\pi_1(G)\cong \pi_1(G/R_u(G))$ so you can assume that $G$ is reductive. Let $A$ be the largest subtorus of $Z(G)$. Then one has a surjection $Z(G)\times G^\mathrm{der}\to G$ with finite abelian kernel. Using the homotopy sequence and the fact that $Z(G)$ obviously has abelian etale fundamental group (it's just some product if $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$'s) we're reduced to the semisimple case. The etale fundamental group of a semisimple group is well-known in characteristic $0$ to agree with its algebraic fundamental group

Comment: (e.g .see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49278/the-algebraic-fundamental-group-of-a-reductive-algebraic-group) and the algebraic fundamental group is patently abelian, it's a quotient of the cocharacter lattice of a maximal torus (see any book on algebraic groups).

Comment: By the lefschetz principle if the field $k$ is of characteristic zero and algebraically closed and if the etale fundamental group is the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group, it follows $\pi_1^{et}(G)$ is abelian for any affine algebraic group of finite type over $k$, hence this settles a part of the question in char $0$.

Comment: @hm2020 You can also go that route, but there are many thorny details lying along the path: invariance (https://web.stanford.edu/~aaronlan/assets/fundamental-group-invariance.pdf), Grothendieck's comparison theorem, etc. It also doesn't really tell you how to compute it without doing the same breakdown that I mentioned in my above comments already. The above also shows how to handle the prime-to-p fundamental group in characteristic $p$. That said, the OP might prefer the Lefschetz principle approach, so who knows.